# How to Click Outside Close Menu Box JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really confused why i still cant do on this js, full 1 day i learn youtube, but stil got nothing, this made me a headache all day.

Here's my codepen: https://codepen.io/nailaahmad/pen/LGRxWJ

simple example i try ad this

```
 $(document).on('click',function(){
   $('.card').collapse('hide');
});
```

and this

```
$('body').click(function(event){
  // check if the clicked element is a descendent of navigation 
  if ($(event.target).closest('.card').length) {
    return; //do nothing if event target is within the navigation
  }
});
```

```js
var $cell = $('.card');

//open and close card when clicked on card
$cell.find('.js-expander').click(function() {

  var $thisCell = $(this).closest('.card');

  if ($thisCell.hasClass('is-collapsed')) {
    $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed').addClass('is-inactive');
    $thisCell.removeClass('is-collapsed').addClass('is-expanded');

    if ($cell.not($thisCell).hasClass('is-inactive')) {
      //do nothing
    } else {
      $cell.not($thisCell).addClass('is-inactive');
    }

  } else {
    $thisCell.removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed');
    $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-inactive');
  }
});

//close card when click on cross
$cell.find('.js-collapser').click(function() {

  var $thisCell = $(this).closest('.card');

  $thisCell.removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed');
  $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-inactive');

});
```

```css
$light-gray: #eceef1;
$gray: darken(#eceef1, 30%);
$slate: darken(#eceef1, 70%);
$turquoise: #1abc9c;
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: $light-gray;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  color: $slate;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 5em auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

.header {
  padding: 30px 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
  &__title {
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.1;
  }
  &__subtitle {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: $gray;
    font-family: 'Yesteryear', cursive;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.1;
  }
}

//Grid Container
.cards {
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

//Cards
.card {
  margin: 15px;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 30px);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  //media queries for stacking cards
  @media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    width: calc((100% / 2) - 30px);
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    width: 100%;
  }
  &:hover {
    .card__inner {
      background-color: $turquoise;
      transform: scale(1.05);
    }
  }
  &__inner {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: $gray;
    color: $light-gray;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    &:after {
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    .fa {
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: .25em;
    }
  }
  //Expander
  &__expander {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background-color: $slate;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: $light-gray;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    .fa {
      font-size: 0.75em;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
      &:hover {
        opacity: 0.9;
      }
    }
  }
  &.is-collapsed {
    .card__inner {
      &:after {
        content: "";
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    .card__expander {
      max-height: 0;
      min-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin-top: 0;
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
  &.is-expanded {
    .card__inner {
      background-color: $turquoise;
      &:after {
        content: "";
        opacity: 1;
        display: block;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -30px;
        left: calc(50% - 15px);
        border-left: 15px solid transparent;
        border-right: 15px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 15px solid #333a45;
      }
      //folder open icon
      .fa:before {
        content: "\f115";
      }
    }
    .card__expander {
      max-height: 1000px;
      min-height: 200px;
      overflow: visible;
      margin-top: 30px;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    &:hover {
      .card__inner {
        transform: scale(1);
      }
    }
  }
  &.is-inactive {
    .card__inner {
      pointer-events: none;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
    &:hover {
      .card__inner {
        background-color: $gray;
        transform: scale(1);
      }
    }
  }
}

//Expander Widths
//when 3 cards in a row
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .card:nth-of-type(3n+2) .card__expander {
    margin-left: calc(-100% - 30px);
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(3n+3) .card__expander {
    margin-left: calc(-200% - 60px);
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(3n+4) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .card__expander {
    width: calc(300% + 60px);
  }
}

//when 2 cards in a row
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .card:nth-of-type(2n+2) .card__expander {
    margin-left: calc(-100% - 30px);
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(2n+3) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .card__expander {
    width: calc(200% + 30px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="header">
    <h1 class="header__title">Expanding Card Grid</h1>
    <h2 class="header__subtitle">with Flexbox</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="cards">

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" card [ is-collapsed ] ">
      <div class="card__inner [ js-expander ]">
        <span>Card</span>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card__expander">
        <i class="fa fa-close [ js-collapser ]"></i> Expander
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your initial attempt wouldn't have worked is because the box would be expanded and closed instantly.

What you need to do instead is to wrap your expanding code in a timeout of 1 execution cycle, so that in your `document.click` handler you can check if there's any expanded boxes.

Additionally, I've provided a function looking at cursor click coordinates in order to determine if the click was outside of the expanded box.

[Working CodePen here](https://codepen.io/radulupescu/pen/qKdevo)

The full code is:

```
var $cell = $('.card');

//open and close card when clicked on card
$cell.find('.js-expander').click(function() {

    var $thisCell = $(this).closest('.card');
    setTimeout(function () {
        if ($thisCell.hasClass('is-collapsed')) {
            $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed').addClass('is-inactive');
            $thisCell.removeClass('is-collapsed').addClass('is-expanded');

            if ($cell.not($thisCell).hasClass('is-inactive')) {
                //do nothing
            } else {
                $cell.not($thisCell).addClass('is-inactive');
            }

        } else {
            $thisCell.removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed');
            $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-inactive');
        }
    });
});

//close card when click on cross
$cell.find('.js-collapser').click(function() {

    var $thisCell = $(this).closest('.card');

    $thisCell.removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed');
    $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-inactive');

});
```

And the new function to handle click outside is:

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
    if (!$(".is-expanded").length) {return;}

    var expandedCard = $(".is-expanded .card__expander");
    var expandedCardPosition = $(".is-expanded .card__expander").position();

    var expandedCardStartingX = expandedCardPosition.left;
    var expandedCardEndingX = expandedCardStartingX + expandedCard.width();

    var expandedCardStartingY = expandedCardPosition.top;
    var expandedCardEndingY = expandedCardStartingY + expandedCard.height();

    var clickedInside = event.pageX >= expandedCardStartingX && event.pageX <= expandedCardEndingX
        && event.pageY >= expandedCardStartingY && event.pageY <= expandedCardEndingY;

    if (!clickedInside) {
        $(".is-expanded .js-collapser").click();
    }
});
```

Hope this does the job :)

Comment: oh man i feel stupid b4, u are really good, i will try learn step by step for this jquery.

Comment: btw, u need remove that "Remove pointer-events: none; from class .card.is-inactive .card__inner" then perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Remove   **pointer-events: none;** from class **.card.is-inactive .card__inner**

Codepen: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/WyvVvm

updated css:

```
$light-gray: #eceef1;
$gray: darken(#eceef1, 30%);
$slate: darken(#eceef1, 70%);
$turquoise: #1abc9c;

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: $light-gray;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  color: $slate;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 5em auto;
  max-width: 1000px;

  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

.header {
  padding: 30px 30px 0;
  text-align: center;

  &__title {
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.1;
  }
  &__subtitle {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: $gray;
    font-family: 'Yesteryear', cursive;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.1;
  }
}

//Grid Container
.cards {
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

//Cards
.card {
  margin: 15px; 
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 30px);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;

  //media queries for stacking cards
  @media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    width: calc((100% / 2) - 30px);
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    width: 100%;
  }

  &:hover {
    .card__inner {
      background-color: $turquoise;
      transform: scale(1.05);
    }
  }

  &__inner {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;

    background-color: $gray;
    color: $light-gray;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;

    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;

    &:after {
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

    .fa {
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: .25em;
    }
  }

  //Expander
  &__expander {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background-color: $slate;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: $light-gray;
    font-size: 1.5em;

    .fa {
      font-size: 0.75em;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;

      &:hover {
        opacity: 0.9;
      }
    }
  }

  &.is-collapsed {

    .card__inner {
      &:after {
        content: "";
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    .card__expander {
      max-height: 0;
      min-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin-top: 0;
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }

  &.is-expanded {

    .card__inner {
      background-color: $turquoise;

      &:after{
        content: "";
        opacity: 1;
        display: block;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -30px;
        left: calc(50% - 15px);
        border-left: 15px solid transparent;
        border-right: 15px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 15px solid #333a45;
      }

      //folder open icon
      .fa:before {
        content: "\f115";
      }
    }

    .card__expander {
      max-height: 1000px;
      min-height: 200px;
      overflow: visible;
      margin-top: 30px;
      opacity: 1;
    }

    &:hover {
      .card__inner {
        transform: scale(1);
      }
    }
  }

  &.is-inactive {
    .card__inner {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }

    &:hover {
      .card__inner {
        background-color: $gray;
        transform: scale(1);
      }
    }
  }
}


//Expander Widths

//when 3 cards in a row
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {

  .card:nth-of-type(3n+2) .card__expander {
    margin-left: calc(-100% - 30px);
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(3n+3) .card__expander {
    margin-left: calc(-200% - 60px);
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(3n+4) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .card__expander {
    width: calc(300% + 60px);
  }

}

//when 2 cards in a row
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

  .card:nth-of-type(2n+2) .card__expander {
    margin-left: calc(-100% - 30px);
  }
  .card:nth-of-type(2n+3) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .card__expander {
    width: calc(200% + 30px);
  }

}
```

Comment: idk if this really simple like that XD, btw this not like my question, but im use this, i like ur idea, really thanks to.

Comment: i cant believe, when i see u just say remove that pointer-events: none;, after i try, wtf, this so funny, when i try everything, u say do that, omg.

Comment: i not expected this, but but i really like this, u make that be perfect, and cuz u i know if css can make mouse cant click outside like that.

Comment: ok thanks but accepted js based answer so i thought this solution is not useful. It's simple way to fix issue